# PHP Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found weird

Tags: php, pdo, system

```
Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in /home/bluminat/public_html/donate/inc/page.viewall.php on line 10
```

Tht file's code:

```
<center>
<div class="panel panel-default" style="width: 600px;">
<div class="panel-heading">Recent Donations</div>
<div class="panel-body"><p>
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting(-1);
require_once('./inc/pagination.php');
try{
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.SQL_HOST.';dbname='.SQL_DB, SQL_USER, SQL_PASS);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    }
    if(isset($_GET['page'])){$page = $_GET['page'];}else{$page = 1;}
    $options = array(    'results_per_page' => 5,    'url' => '?page=*VAR*',    'db_handle' => $dbh);
    try{
    $paginate = new pagination($page, 'SELECT * FROM donations_list ORDER BY date DESC', $options);}catch(paginationException $e){    echo $e;    exit();}
    if($paginate->success == true){$result = $paginate->resultset->fetchAll();?>
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>User</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    foreach($result as $row)    {
    echo '<tr><td><a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Click to view Steam Profile" href="http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.$row['community_id'].'">'.$row['steam_name'].'</a> (<span class="text-muted">'.$row['steam_id2'].'</span>)</td><td>'.$row['amount'].'</td><td>'.$row['date'].'</td></tr>';    }}?>
    </center>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </p>
    <?php echo $paginate->links_html; ?>
    <?php echo '<p>Total Donations: <span class="text-muted">'.$paginate->total_results.'</span></p>'; ?>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Its weird because on this same script works fine on my other web server.. Not sure why im having this problem here... Please help, any help is apreciated. Just really confused on why this is happening.. If you want the page its http://bluminati.tk/donate (click view all donations on the bottom of that page)

Comment: Do you have the PDO drivers installed? Check `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Your webserver may not have the PDO extension installed, while the other might. Like @Marty said, check phpinfo() and contact your hosting provider about a way to remedy that.

Comment: Thank you @lxndr I made the php file that shows all the info about the php config http://bluminati.tk/info.php and your right! It says pdo is disabled.. i've contacted my hosting provider.. thanks!! :D